# Movement shortcut to navigate to next form in vim for clojure

Tags: vim, plugins, clojure

I'm using `tpope/vim-fireplace`, `guns/vim-sexp` and `tpope/vim-sexp-mappings-for-regular-people`.

I'm not an vim expert so I wonder how you manage navigation like this scenario. Let's say your cursor is at the position where the first dash is and you want to jump to where the second dash is.

```
(defn fibo [n]
-
  (loop [a 1 b 1 counter n fibos [1 1]]
    (if (= counter 2)
      (seq fibos)
      -
      (recur b (+ a b) (- counter 1) (conj fibos (+ a b))))))
```

I would expect pressing `(` would eventually bring me there but it stays at the top form.

And a similar navigation trick

```
(defn fibo [n]
  (loop [a 1 b 1 counter n fibos [1 1]]
  *     *                        *
    (if (= counter 2)
      (seq fibos)
      (recur b (+ a b) (- counter 1) (conj fibos (+ a b))))))
```

From first star, to the second, then to the third?

Comment: You can map a custom key to move to next '('.

    :nmap ( /(<cr>:nohl<cr> 
or

    :nmap ( /[([]<cr>:nohl<cr>

if you want stop at '[' too.

Comment: @chendesheng thanks, I wonder a bit about the conventions too, is my attempt a sensible one or are there any other established movement tricks for structured lisp data?

Answer (score 0):

For the second scenario:

<kbd>f</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> to move the first [

and then you can repeat the action with <kbd>;</kbd> to go to the next [